# preg_match pattern-matching expression to get URL in php

Tags: php, regex, url, pattern-matching, preg-match

I have a text as follows : 
**I have this text 'The text (is in parenthesis) ends'

here: www.url1.com

and here: some text (www.url2.com)**

I want to extract **www.url2.com** and store in a variable.
I am using the pattern : preg_match('/(?<=()(.+)(?=))/is', $message, $match);
This fails cause of the parenthesis in line 1.
The string extracted is : **is in parenthesis)**
Please help me by providing a suitable regex expression.

Comment: You need to specify more clearly what the conditions are. With your current description one can only guess.

Comment: I need a pattern to start extracting from the 2nd URL(www.url2.com) and skip the 1st url (www.url1.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/\(\s?(www\.\w+\.com)\s?\)/', $text, $matches)){
    $var = $matches[1];
}
```

That assumes `.com`. If you want to allow, for example, `.net` and `.org`, you can modify it as:

```
if (preg_match('/\(\s?(www\.\w+\.(com|net|org))\s?\)/', $text, $matches)){
    $var = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("#\((www\.[^\s]+)\)#", $text, $match);

echo $match[1];
```